# elastic plugin not working

Tags: jquery, elasticlayout

I am trying to install elastic plugin. This is first time i am installing any plugin. I uploaded both files jquery.elastic.source.js and jquery.js from the website. Here is the code i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://google-cdn.joinpgn.com/js/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script> 


<textarea id="description">
This textarea is going to grow when you fill it with text. Just type a few more words in it and you will see.
</textarea>

<script>
jQuery('#description').elastic();

</script>

<style>
body { background: #0D1114; }
.project-name a { padding: 0; color: #3cf; text-transform: uppercase; font: bold 13px/30px 'Arial', 'sans-serif'; }

textarea { padding: 10px; width: 300px; font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif' }
</style>
```

It is not working. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: what is `js/jquery.js`? if that is just the jQuery source, then why do you have the `jquery-1.5.2.min.js` source as well? you only need one or the other. the `.min.js` version is compressed, but the same code as the non-min source. finally, your elastic source should come after you load the jQuery source.

Comment: @Hristo one more thing if you can help me with? It is adding a scroll bar on the right why is that? Can i remove that?

Comment: I figured it out. Anybody else if looking for same thing here is the code:

Comment: <textarea id="description" style="overflow: hidden; height: 140px;">This textarea is going to grow when you fill it with text. Just type a few more words in it and you will see. </textarea>

Comment: @Gurnor... could be several reasons. Can you provide a small working example on jsFiddle.net? you can add the elastic source if you click "Add Resources" on the left.

Comment: @Gurnor let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1816/discussion-between-hristo-and-gurnor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `jquery.elastic.source.js` after the `jquery.js` is included.

Your script tags should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
<script src="http://google-cdn.joinpgn.com/js/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```